# How to pay ER bills after collision in someone else's vehicle

Tags: car-insurance, medical-bill

Which insurance(s) should I contact to file claims in the following situation?

I have auto insurance for my vehicles with the usual coverages including personal injury protection, which I understand covers medical bills or other bills.

The policy is under my name and my spouse's name; since children are below driving age, they never asked for their names.

I also have the usual health insurance, AD&D, etc. This explicitly covers me, my spouse, and dependent children.

Today, one child was properly restrained in the back seat while riding with cousins in the cousins' family vehicle being driving by their parent, and they were involved in a collision.

Everyone is alright, but they went to the emergency room to get checked out.

The ER took our health insurance information and we walked out paying our typical co-pay/co-insurance via my HSA account.

What is the best way for me to proceed in this situation?

When I get the full bill from the ER, do I get my health insurance to pay and keep the co-pay/co-insurance on the HSA account?

Would my auto insurance's PIP cover the child and should I open a claim with the auto insurance to pay the bill instead?

Should one pay for the majority of the bill and the other pay for the co-pay/co-insurance and I leave my HSA account untouched?

*Edit:* The US state in which all this occurred is Texas; our insurance is also in Texas.

Comment: Easiest to call the insurance companies involved rather than speculate, medical coverage from auto could be secondary rather than primary, the sibling/in-law's insurance might be covering.

Comment: If I remember my insurance classes correctly (it had been a while), I believe this varies by state insurance regulations, and where not decided by law companies have generally come to agreements about who pays for who. Similarly, who's fault the accident was matters only depending on the state. I think it's usually easiest to contact your regular health insurance company, tell them the situation, and go from there. For any useful answer here, I believe you'll need to include the state (I'm assuming US).

Comment: It's difficult to see why your auto insurance should cover anything, as it wasn't your vehicle, and you weren't the driver.  Surely it would be the cousin's auto insurance (or the other driver's, if they were at fault) that should pay?